# Started receiving CORS issue from two different apps I have deployed to Heroku around 6 months ego

Tags: reactjs, heroku

everything was working fine and I did not change anything.
any ideas what may be causing that? Heroku update?
I couldn't figure out what is the reason it started.
this is the server snippet:

```
const db = knex({
    client : 'pg',
    connection: {
        connectionString : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: true,
    }
});    

const app=express()    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

const database ={
    users: [
        {
            id: '123',
            name: 'XX',
            email: 'XX',
            password: 'XX',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        }
    ]
}

app.get('/',(req, res)=> {res.send(database.users)})    
app.post('/signin',(req, res)=> {signin.handleSignin(req, res, db, bcrypt)})
app.post('/register',(req, res)=> {register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt)})
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {profile.handleProfileGet(req, res, db)})
app.put('/image', (req, res )=> {image.handleImage(req, res, db)})
app.post('/imageurl', (req, res )=> {image.handleApiCall(req, res)})


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=> {
    console.log(`app is running on port ${process.env.PORT} or port 3000`);
})
```

Comment: Try using [Will It CORS](https://httptoolkit.tech/will-it-cors/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically a CORS issue is more of a server side issue rather than the client side, so my thought is that if those 2 projects used some external api which allowed cors before and after a change it started causing the issue. It could be also how you make the requests from the client side but without some code snippet or more information I can't really tell.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, i am adding the server snippet.